# How can we identify ip address of machine from which deployment was done on salesforce

Tags: deployment, ip, salesforce, changeset

There are ways by which a developer can deploy code in salesforce . We want to Identify from which machine the change set was deployed . Can we do that or where can we see that in salesforce ?

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the Setup Audit Trail, you would see the user that made the change and the ip address that the changes came from.

Comment: I can see the username but there is no info about the ip in the audit trail

Comment: The IP address is usually in the Login related list of the user, so once u have the user that made the change you can get the ip address from their user details page login history related list